Alertmanagerconfig Matchers not routing correctly
I have a weird issue with alertmanager.
I have multiple alertmanager configs each matching for specific labels and sending them to a slack channel
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1alpha1
kind: AlertmanagerConfig
metadata:
  name: abc-api
  namespace: abc-sit
  labels:
    alertmanagerConfig: "sit-config"
spec:
  route:
    groupBy: ['alertname', 'namespace']
    groupWait: '5m'
    groupInterval: '5m'
    receiver: 'abc-sit-default'
    repeatInterval: '5m' 
    routes:
      - matchers:
          - name: 'alert_source'
            value: 'abc-api'
            matchType: =~
        receiver: 'abc-sit-default'
      - matchers:
          - name: alert_source
            value: ''
            matchType: =~
        receiver: 'null'
  receivers:
    - name: 'null'
      webhookConfigs: []
    - name: 'abc-sit-default'
      slackConfigs:
        - sendResolved: true
          apiURL:
            name: "abc-api-prom"
            key: defaultWebhook
          channel: "#abc-api-nonprod-alerts"
          title: |-
            [{{ .Status | toUpper }}{{ if eq .Status "firing" }}:{{ .Alerts.Firing | len }}{{ end }}] {{ .CommonLabels.alertname }} for {{ .CommonLabels.deployment }} in {{ .CommonLabels.environment }}
          text: |-
            *Alert:* {{ .CommonAnnotations.summary }}

And another one:

apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1alpha1
kind: AlertmanagerConfig
metadata:
  name: xyz
  namespace: xyz-sit
  labels:
    alertmanagerConfig: "sit-config"
spec:
  route:
    groupBy: ['alertname', 'namespace']
    groupWait: '30s'
    groupInterval: '5m'
    repeatInterval: '15m'
    receiver: 'xyz-sit-default'
    routes:
      - matchers:
          - name: severity
            value: critical
            matchType: =~
          - name: alert_source
            value: xyz
            matchType: =~
        receiver: 'xyz-sit-critical'
      - matchers:
          - name: severity
            value: warning
            matchType: =~
          - name: alert_source
            value: xyz
            matchType: =~
        receiver: 'xyz-sit-warning'
      - matchers:
          - name: alert_source
            value: xyz
            matchType: =~
        receiver: 'xyz-sit-default'
      - matchers:
          - name: alert_source
            value: ""
            matchType: =~
        receiver: 'null'
  receivers:
    - name: 'null'
      webhookConfigs: []
    - name: 'xyz-sit-default'
      slackConfigs:
        - sendResolved: true
          apiURL:
            name: "xyz-prom"
            key: defaultWebhook
          channel: "#alert-testing"
          title: |-
            [{{ .Status | toUpper }}{{ if eq .Status "firing" }}:{{ .Alerts.Firing | len }}{{ end }}] {{ .CommonLabels.alertname }} for {{ .CommonLabels.deployment }} in {{ .CommonLabels.environment }}
          text: |-
            *Alert:* {{ .CommonAnnotations.summary }}
    - name: 'xyz-sit-critical'
      slackConfigs:
        - sendResolved: true
          apiURL:
            name: "xyz-prom"
            key: critical
          channel: "#alert-testing"
          title: |-
            [{{ .Status | toUpper }}{{ if eq .Status "firing" }}:{{ .Alerts.Firing | len }}{{ end }}] {{ .CommonLabels.alertname }} for {{ .CommonLabels.deployment }} in {{ .CommonLabels.environment }}
          text: |-
            *Alert:* {{ .CommonAnnotations.summary }}
    - name: 'xyz-sit-warning'
      slackConfigs:
        - sendResolved: true
          apiURL:
            name: "xyz-prom"
            key: warning
          channel: "#alert-testing"
          title: |-
            [{{ .Status | toUpper }}{{ if eq .Status "firing" }}:{{ .Alerts.Firing | len }}{{ end }}] {{ .CommonLabels.alertname }} for {{ .CommonLabels.deployment }} in {{ .CommonLabels.environment }}
          text: |-
            *Alert:* {{ .CommonAnnotations.summary }}

And a third one:
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1alpha1
kind: AlertmanagerConfig
metadata:
  name: dfg
  namespace: dfg-sit
  labels:
    alertmanagerConfig: "sit-config"
spec:
  route:
    groupBy: ['alertname', 'namespace']
    groupWait: '30s'
    groupInterval: '2m'
    repeatInterval: '5m'
    receiver: 'dfg-sit-default'
    routes:
      - matchers:
          - name: severity
            value: critical
            matchType: =~
          - name: alert_source
            value: dfg
            matchType: =~
        receiver: 'dfg-sit-critical'
      - matchers:
          - name: severity
            value: warning
            matchType: =~
          - name: alert_source
            value: dfg
            matchType: =~
        receiver: 'dfg-sit-warning'
      - matchers:
          - name: alert_source
            value: dfg
            matchType: =~
        receiver: 'dfg-sit-default'
      - matchers:
          - name: alert_source
            value: ""
            matchType: =~
        receiver: 'null'
  receivers:
    - name: 'null'
      webhookConfigs: []
    - name: 'dfg-sit-default'
      slackConfigs:
        - sendResolved: true
          apiURL:
            name: "dfg-prom"
            key: defaultWebhook
          channel: "#dfg-nonprod-alerts"
          title: |-
            [{{ .Status | toUpper }}{{ if eq .Status "firing" }}:{{ .Alerts.Firing | len }}{{ end }}] {{ .CommonLabels.alertname }} for {{ .CommonLabels.deployment }} in {{ .CommonLabels.environment }}
          text: |-
            *Alert:* {{ .CommonAnnotations.summary }}
    - name: 'dfg-sit-critical'
      slackConfigs:
        - sendResolved: true
          apiURL:
            name: "dfg-prom"
            key: critical
          channel: "#dfg-nonprod-alerts"
          title: |-
            [{{ .Status | toUpper }}{{ if eq .Status "firing" }}:{{ .Alerts.Firing | len }}{{ end }}] {{ .CommonLabels.alertname }} for {{ .CommonLabels.deployment }} in {{ .CommonLabels.environment }}
          text: |-
            *Alert:* {{ .CommonAnnotations.summary }}
    - name: 'dfg-sit-warning'
      slackConfigs:
        - sendResolved: true
          apiURL:
            name: "dfg-prom"
            key: warning
          channel: "#dfg-nonprod-alerts"
          title: |-
            [{{ .Status | toUpper }}{{ if eq .Status "firing" }}:{{ .Alerts.Firing | len }}{{ end }}] {{ .CommonLabels.alertname }} for {{ .CommonLabels.deployment }} in {{ .CommonLabels.environment }}
          text: |-
            *Alert:* {{ .CommonAnnotations.summary }}

I have Prometheus rules in place and with that extra label.
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: PrometheusRule
metadata:
  labels:
    prometheus: kube-prometheus-stack-prometheus
    role: alert-rules
    alert_source: abc-api
  name: abc-alerts
  namespace: ms-devops-sit
spec:
  groups:
    - name: pod-rules
      rules:
        - alert: ShortReplicaCount
          expr: kube_deployment_status_replicas{deployment="abc"} - kube_deployment_status_replicas_available{deployment="abc"} == 0
          for: 5m
          labels:
            severity: critical
            alert_source: abc-api
          annotations:
            summary: 'Pod for deployment: `{{ $labels.deployment }}` could not start in namespace: `{{ $labels.namespace }}`'

So what happens is when an alert is firing some times it goes to the correct channel and other times it goes to the other channels, randomly, it's happening with all PrometheusRules
